# Solr curl connection failing using CURL

Tags: solr

Im trying to use CURL to connect to SOLR db but my curl does not give any response...

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:8983/solr/#/collection1/select?q=*:*'
```

The web interface works very welll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the fragment identifier (hash mark)

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=*:*'
```

Comment: It's for UI, the actual call to the server is displayed on the right